# SQL: calculate statistics from timestamped table

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have a table (let's call it `status_log`) that has the following columns:

```
id  entity_id  status_id  created_at
```

All the columns are not nullable and of type `uuid` apart from the last one which is as the name suggests is a `timestamptz`.

Every time a `status` of `entity` changes, a new row is added to this table with a new `status_id` and current `created_at` timestamp (note that the previous records are not deleted).

I need to write a query that would do the following:

**Calculate the number of entries for a custom array of `status_id`'s for each day over a custom period of time**

*Explanation:*

Let's say we are given an array of `status_id`'s `[1, 2, 3]` and two timestamps `10` and `20`. Then I would need to calculate how many `entities` had **each** of given `status`'es over the given period of time

*Example:*

Data in the table (for simplicity reasons, `created_at` is given as an integer, you may treat it as a day)

```
id  entity_id  status_id   created_at
1   1          1           4 
2   2          2           6 
3   3          2           7 
4   2          1           8 
5   1          2           10
```

Input statuses: `[1, 2]`

Input period of time: `from 4 till 10`

Expected output:

```
Array<dayNumber: {
    statusId: count
}>
```

```
[
4: {
   1: 1,
   2: 0
},
5: {
   1: 1,
   2: 0
},
6: {
   1: 1,
   2: 1
},
7: {
   1: 1,
   2: 2
},
8: {
   1: 2,
   2: 1
},
9: {
   1: 2,
   2: 1
},
10: {
   1: 1,
   2: 2
},
]
```

**Assumptions:**

You may assume that the time period range will always include at least one day so there is always something to display.

**Technical requirements:**

The query has to be very efficient as the number of rows inside the table can potentially be 30k+

**What I have tried so far:**

Honestly, I don't really know where to start, it seems like an advanced query to me so after hours of research and trial & error I couldn't reach something that's worth putting here. Any help/guidance is highly appreciated!